# Few confusing things about expressing relationships with References and Repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design

• We can express an *association* between two entities via **object reference** ( though a relationship between *Aggregate root* and its *internal entity* could also be expressed via a *method defined on a root* --> `SomeRootEnt.BorrowMeIntEnt(...)`  ) or via **Repository**, which would retrieve *related entities* from a database. 
• When relationship is expressed via *Repository*, *client* would directly call a *Repository* to obtain *related entity(ies)* 
• The decision on how to express a *relationship* is based on whether this *relationship* is required for *maintaining an integrity* ( and perhaps on whether *behavior* requires *association* to be able to express itself )

1) If *relationship* ( say **1:*** ) is expressed via *Repository*, are *child entities* required to contain an *ID* of a *parent entity* ( Note: this question is assuming that either at least a parent is a root or that they all reside within same aggregate )?

2) The *relationship* between *entities in different aggregates* should only be expressed by *IDs*

a) Why?

b) Wouldn't such a *relationship* essentially be expressed via *Repository*?

c) If yes to **b)**, this would also suggest that *associations* between *entities in different aggregates* in most cases aren't required for the purpose of supporting a particular *behavior*? If yes, why?

**UPDATE:**

2a)

> Expressing relationship with an identity reference is different from
>   expressing the relationship with an object reference. The reason that
>   the relationship should be expressed with an identity is to maintain
>   transactional integrity - ie only a single aggregate will be modified
>   in any given transaction. If an object reference was used, two
>   aggregates could be affected by a transaction.

I - I understand the point you're trying to make, since if relationship would be expressed with an *object reference*, then simply for the fact that aggregate A1 ( which is being modified ) is "physically" connected to another aggregate A2, it means one of A1's parts ( ie A2 <--  in reality A2 is not really a part of A1, but hopefully you understand the point ) is not in sync with other parts?!

II - But conceptually speaking, if we modify A1, then even if the relationship between the two is not expressed using *object reference*, the two aggregates are still out of sync, so in practical terms, what difference does it make whether A1 and A2 are physically connected?

III - Anyways, why couldn't we in BOTH cases simply use *eventual consistency*?

**SECOND UPDATE:**

original_2)

> To be clear, relationships between root entities (ARs) should be
>   expressed with identities. References between non-root entities in
>   distinct aggregates should be forbidden.

Can we have unidirectional associations traversable only from *A1 non-root entity(ies)*  to *A2 root entity* ( ie *non-root entity* in A1 would contain ID of A2 root )?

2)
a)

I.

> If an object reference was used, two aggregates could be affected by a
>   transaction.
>
> It creates a possibility of A2 being modified in the transaction which
>   is modifying A1. Referencing A2 by identity eliminates this
>   possibility. Also, things such as database locking won't apply to A2
>   when loading A1.

Ignoring for a moment the fact that DB locking won't apply to A2 when updating A1 - why shouldn't we in certain situations allow both A1 and A2 to be modified within a single transaction?

I know aggregates define consistency boundary, but if in rare cases we need both A1 and A2 to be synchronized within same transaction, then only other alternative may be to convert both A1 and A2 into a single aggregate, which in that particular model may not be appropriate?!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. For example, suppose you have a customer with orders. To get all the orders for a customer, you can select all orders with a corresponding CustomerId via orders repository.

2) To be clear, relationships between root entities (ARs) should be expressed with identities. References between non-root entities in distinct aggregates should be forbidden.

2a) Expressing relationship with an identity reference is different from expressing the relationship with an object reference. The reason that the relationship should be expressed with an identity is to maintain transactional integrity - ie only a single aggregate will be modified in any given transaction. If an object reference was used, two aggregates could be affected by a transaction.

2b) Yes. A repository allows the traversal and the identity expresses the relationship.

2c) This is the whole point of an aggregate - it should define a consistency boundary. If changes to an aggregate should affect aggregates, those changes should be capable of being applied in an eventually consistent manner.

**UPDATE**

2a1) It creates a possibility of A2 being modified in the transaction which is modifying A1. Referencing A2 by identity eliminates this possibility. Also, things such as database locking won't apply to A2 when loading A1.

2a2) If the transaction which modifies A1 results in changes that need to be applied to A2, those changes will be synchronized *eventually*. The reason for keeping them physically separate are stated in 2a1.

2a3) You could, but again, reasons specified in 2a1 explain why it is better to use identity references.

**UPDATE 2**

2) I suppose if the integrity of the two ARs is maintained and the reference makes life a lot easier it can be acceptable. The reference is not itself a problem, it can lead to problems.

2a1) One reason for this is rooted in more modern document database architectures. Document databases usually only support atomic transactions on a single document. Another reason is that two ARs may be stored in different databases, in which case a distributed transaction would be required to maintain consistency. However, a relational database can certainly lock multiple tables and so a scenario where two ARs are modified in a transaction are possible. As a result, these constraints should be understood as guidelines. If all ramifications are understood and caution is used, then it can be acceptable to update two ARs.

Comment: "1) Yes. For example, suppose you have a customer with orders. To get all the orders for a customer, you can select all orders with a corresponding CustomerId via orders repository." What I meant to ask was whether it'd be preferable to only have a CustomerId field in Orders table, but we wouldn't map this field to a property of Order entity? That way relationship wouldn't be expressed in a model, but we would still be able to select related orders by supplying corresponding CustomerId to OrderRepository ( though I now have hard time imagining when this design would actually be useful )?!

Comment: It would be possible but I think having a CustomerId on the order object is important, at least for declarative purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by "declarative"?

Comment: Oh, perhaps that person reading the code can just by seeing CustomerId property immediately conclude that Customer and Order have a relationship?

Comment: Yes it declares the relationship. The customerId may also be used for certain behaviors.

Comment: Apologies, but I just thought of something. Can you see the update?

Comment: I worded original_2 question wrongly, since I meant to ask whether it is ok to for A1 non-root entities to express relationship with A2 root entity with an identity refrence ( ie A1 non-root would contain ID of A2 root entity )? But I will mark your post tomorrow regardless if you answer this or not. Anyways, excellent answers

Comment: It can be OK if integrity is maintained. A specific scenario could affect the decision.

Comment: Are you implying that A1 non root entity(ies) having ( unidirectional ) identity reference with A2 root ( ie relationship is expressed using a Repository ) is more problematic ( as far as integrity is concerned ) than identity reference between two roots?

Comment: It can be, but it can also be OK. The main point is that aggregates should be thought of as conceptual wholes. A specific use case can have unique characteristics that can affect the decision.

Comment: Ok, final question. Why is ( unidirectional ) identity reference between A1 non-root entity and A2 root entity more problematic than identity reference between A1 and A2 roots?

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't see anything wrong with that and its rather common. I was thinking about references to a non-root in another aggregate...